# Javascript variables from text box

Tags: javascript

How would you make the feature that when you type anything into a text box when you hit enter or submit, the thing that you typed is displayed under the text box. The text box would then clear so that you can write more things, like the comment feature on Facebook?

I do not want it to be a popup.

Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<input onclick="myFunction()" type="text">

<script>

function myFunction()

{

var x;

var person=prompt("Please enter your name");

if (person!=null)



</script>
<p id="demo">

<script>
function myFunction()

{
x="Hello " + person;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just need to use `+=` instead of `+`, to append new text rather than overwriting the contents each time...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's a copy/paste error, but there are a lot of errors:

- You can't split your javascript like that
- use `+=` instead of `+`

  function myFunction() {

  ```
      var x;
      var person=prompt("Please enter your name");
      if (person!=null)

      x="Hello " + person;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += (x + "</br>");
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery, take a look on the simplest [example](http://jsfiddle.net/SJK8N/) and here is a part of the code:

```
$('input').on('keyup', function (e) {
  if ((e.keyCode || e.which) == 13) { 
     // if enter pressed - get text 
     var text = $(this).val();
     // append
     $('div').append('<p>' + text + '</p>');
     // and clear the field
     $(this).val('');
  }
});
```